# Number rows in Column A based on values in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what I'm trying to do using Excel 2010 VBA:
I have a list of course names in column B. Each time the course name changes I've inserted two blank rows. What I need to do is number the rows in column A, stop numbering when I hit a blank row and then restart the numbering when I get a new course name in column B. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, vba is required. The formula from Ken works fine but the number of rows this is needed for is typically over 60K and this numbering step is just one part of a larger series of macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easier than VBA.  Put this formula in A2, and copy down

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",MAX(A$1:A1)+1)
```